# How to host a WCF Service with an SVC file

Tags: wcf

I am trying to deploy a SP web part to a new SP server. I read that I need to set up a WCF Service first before I can deploy it. I have all the files used from the web part's first deployment and verified that, with a few line alterations, that the code should be fine to recompile on the new SP server.

The files already have a .svc file, which is verified to be fine. I am trying to follow guides on hosting a WCF service and I'm a little lost on them since I already have the .svc. I know it's not as simple as dropping it in the /_vti_bin folder, so how do I proceed?

The SVC file is written and used for SharePoint 2007. I am using SharePoint 2010.

Answer (score 0):

Start with creating a new web service using VS and SP2010, this should be good way to start with .

http://www.thesharepointblog.net/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?List=815f255a-d0ef-4258-be2a-28487dc9975c&ID=64